# Creating a CSS3 box-shadow on all sides but one

Tags: html, css, shadow

I've got a tabbed navigation bar where I'd like the open tab to have a shadow to set it apart from the other tabs. I'd also like the whole tab section to have a single shadow (see bottom horizontal line) going up, shading the bottom of all tabs except for the open one.

I'm going to use CSS3's `box-shadow` property to do it, but I can't figure out a way to shade only the parts I want.

Normally I'd cover up the bottom shadow of the open tab with the content area (higher `z-index`), but in this case the content area itself has a shadow so that would just wind up covering the tab.

#### Tab layout

```
     _______    _______    _______
    |       |  |       |  |       |
____|_______|__|       |__|_______|______
```

#### Shadow line.

Shadow would go up from the horizontal lines, and outward of the vertical lines.

```
                _______
               |       |
_______________|       |_________________
```

[Here](http://www.apwit.com/aplacetoputthings/tabs.html) is a live example:

Any help out there, geniuses?

Comment: @the_drow Re: CSS3, I like to consider design features like drop shadows, rounded corners, etc. a reward for those users who use modern browsers.

Comment: WOW this is exactly exactly what I needed, glad a question already exists. I too want to apply this to a tab exactly like you showed, wow wow wow :D

Comment: One more great way of solving this problem is using pseudo elements, see my answer for more details.

Comment: See details for pseudo-element-solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38372215/4769218

Comment: I know this is an old question, but are the size of the tabs known? Or are they flexible? I can imagine the height might be set, but not the width?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In your sample create a div inside #content with this style

```css
#content_over_shadow {
    padding: 1em;
    position: relative; /* look at this */
    background:#fff;    /* a solid background (non transparent) */
}
```

and change #content style (remove paddings) and add shadow

```css
#content {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px #888; /* line shadow */
}
```

add shadows to tabs:

```css
#nav li a {
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: .7em .5em .5em .5em;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px #888; /* the shadow */
}
```

Comment: There's something missing from this solution. Editing his code and applying the styles recommended, you still end up with a shadow over the 'selected' tab. Seems as though there is an overflow: hidden missing?

Comment: Yep. You would need an overflow: hidden on the nav to make it work.

Comment: The 'line shadow' shown in `#content_over_shadow` should actually be in `#content`'s style.

Comment: Well this solution mabe were correct in 2009, but now it is not. Correct answer is http://stackoverflow.com/a/9800481/835753

Comment: A solution with pseudo element: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38372215/4769218

Answer (score 28):

Cut it off with overflow.

```css
div div {box-shadow:0 0 5px #000; height:20px}
div {overflow:hidden;height:25px; padding:5px 5px 0 5px}
```

```html
<div><div>tab</div></div>
```

Comment: Here's also an example with cutting it off with overflow http://starikovs.com/2011/11/09/css3-one-side-shadow/.

Comment: This method will only work when it is the bottom side that you don't want the shadow on

Comment: Works great! The parent div can be placed on the correct `z-index`

Comment: I'm currently using this solution i'am getting some troubles with child element that need to overflow (as facebook like button).

Comment: Not very useful for most responsive designs as you have to set the height of the elements

Comment: Solution with pseudo element: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38372215/4769218

Comment: Combining with with negative margins on the parent container work wonderfully

Answer (score 13):

You can use multiple CSS shadows without any other divs to get desired effect, with the caveat of of no shadows around the corners.

```css
div.shadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -3px 3px -3px black, 3px 0px 3px -3px black, -3px 0px 3px -3px black;
    -moz-box-shadow:    0 -3px 3px -3px black, 3px 0px 3px -3px black, -3px 0px 3px -3px black;
    box-shadow:         0 -3px 3px -3px black, 3px 0px 3px -3px black, -3px 0px 3px -3px black;
    height: 25px
}
```

```html
 <div style="height: 25px"><div class="shadow">tab</div></div>
```

Overall though its very unintrusive.

Comment: This would be a great solution, but as you say, the corners are wonky.
http://jsfiddle.net/mahemoff/ZStTr/

Comment: Worked like a charm for my inset shadow needs with rounded corners.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

### Update:

`clip-path` is now (2020) supported in all major browsers.

---

### Original Answer:

If you are willing to use experimental technology with only [partial support](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path), you could use the [`clip-path` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).

This will produce the desired effect: a box shadow on the top, left and right sides with a clean cut-off on the bottom edge.

In your case you would use clip-path: inset(px px px px); where the pixel values are calculated from the edge in question (see below).

```
#container {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px #888;
    clip-path: inset(-8px -8px 0px -8px);
}
```

This will clip the div in question at:

- 8 pixels above the top (to include the shadow)
- 8 pixels outside of the right edge (to include the shadow)
- 0 pixels from the bottom (to hide the shadow)
- 8 pixels outside of the left edge (to include the shadow)

Note that no commas are required between pixel values.

The size of the div can be flexible.

Comment: Unfortunately there is a gap where the two shadows overlap.

Comment: @sbaechler can you elaborate? Where do the shadows overlap?

Answer (score 11):

One more, rather creative, way of solving this problem is adding :after or :before pseudo element to one of the elements. In my case it looks like this:

```
#magik_megamenu>li:hover>a:after {
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3px;
    left: 0;
}
```

See the screenshot, made the pseudo element red to make it more visible.

[image: See the screenshot, made the pseudo element red to make it more visible.]

Answer (score 7):

Personally I like the solution found here best: http://css3pie.com/demos/tabs/

It allows you to have a zero state or a hover state with a background color that still has the shadow from the content below overlaying it. Not sure that's possible with the method above:

[image: shadowed tab with hover state]

UPDATE:

Actually I was incorrect. You can make the accepted solution support the hover state shown above. Do this:

Instead of having the positive relative on the a, put it on the a.active class with a z-index that is higher than your #content div below (which has the shadow on it) but is lower than the z-index on your content_wrapper.

For example:

```
<nav class="ppMod_Header clearfix">
    <h1 class="ppMod_PrimaryNavigation-Logo"><a class="ppStyle_Image_Logo" href="/">My company name</a></h1>
    <ul class="ppList_PrimaryNavigation ppStyle_NoListStyle clearfix">
        <li><a href="/benefits">Benefits</a></li>
        <li><a class="ppStyle_Active" href="/features">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="/company">Company</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="ppPage-Body">
    <div id="ppPage-BodyWrap">
        content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

then with your css:

```
#ppPage-Body
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px rgba(0,0,0,.75)
    position: relative /* IMPORTANT PART */

#ppPage-BodyWrap
    background: #F4F4F4
    position: relative /* IMPORTANT PART */
    z-index: 4 /* IMPORTANT PART */


.ppList_PrimaryNavigation li a:hover
    background: #656565
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0

.ppList_PrimaryNavigation li a.ppStyle_Active
    background: #f4f4f4
    color: #222
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)
    position: relative /* IMPORTANT PART */
    z-index: 3 /* IMPORTANT PART */
```

Answer (score 5):

you can cover up shadow using multiple box shadows as well.

box-shadow: 0 10px 0 #fff, 0 0 10px #ccc;

Comment: Easiest solution for my case!

Answer (score 1):

If you added two spans to hook onto then you could use two, something like:

```
box-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #000;
```

on one span and

```
box-shadow: 1px -1px 1px #000;
```

on another. Might work!

If the shadows overlap you could even use 3 shadows - one 1px to the left, one 1px to the right and one 1px up, or however thick you want them.

Answer (score 0):

I did a sort of hack, not perfect, but it looks okay:

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li class="tab active"> Tab 1 </li>
<li class="tab"> Tab 2 </li>
<li class="tab"> Tab 3 </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">Content of tab goes here</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
 .tabs { list-style-type: none; display:flex;align-items: flex-end;
  .tab {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    border: 1px solid $vivosBorderGrey2;
    background-color:$vivosBorderGrey2;
    color: $vivosWhite;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 2px;
    font-size: 14px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s;
    &.active {
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border-color: #eee;
      color: $vivosMedGrey;
      border-bottom-color: transparent;
      box-shadow: 0px -3px 8px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    &:hover {padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
   } 

.tabContent {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding:10px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.