# drop shadow with tabs not working properly

Tags: css, tabs, dropshadow

I am trying to implement the solution listed here:

[Creating a CSS3 box-shadow on all sides but one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429605/css3-box-shadow-all-sides-but-one/1451207#1451207)

I created this jsfiddle using that guys code, adding overflow:hidden to #nav. You can see it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/eeTUJ/

The thing that is still missing is the shadow of the content on the light blue background. Does anyone know how to get it for the main content shadow to appear...?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a z-index to the tab's active and hover state that is higher than #content_over_shadow. I added:

```
z-index: 20;
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/eeTUJ/2/