# How to box-shadow inset on just the Left, Bottom, Right -- not the top?

Tags: html, css

I have the following box-shadow inset css3 styling:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
```

The inset styling appears on all 4 sides of the box but I do not want styling on the top. How can I remove the styling from the top but keep the styling on the Left, Bottom, Right?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 box-shadow, all sides but one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429605/css3-box-shadow-all-sides-but-one)

Comment: @Clive, I saw that it's not related imo

Answer (score 11):

This is what you want:

```
.right-left-bottom-shadow {
    box-shadow: 5px 0 5px -5px #CCC, 0 5px 5px -5px #CCC, -5px 0 5px -5px #CCC;
}
```

The first one is left, second bottom and last the shadow for the right side. This looks really nice if your border has color `#CCC`.

Comment: I confirm this to be working and supported on all major browsers (IE 9+).

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that with just `box-shadow` so far, but you can composite `box-shadow` with other possibilities like `overflow: hidden`. For example, you can push the top shadow outside of parent element and hide that part with `overflow: hidden`.

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CatChen/Fty2N/3/

Answer (score 0):

No CSS method I know for this but following can be a work around (not a perfect solution)

```
    <div id="mydiv">
       <div class="workaround"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
   #mydiv { 
     background-color:#f00;
     height:100px;
     width:100px;
     box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
     padding:0 2px;
  }
 #mydiv .workaround {
    background-color:#f00;
    width:100%;
    height:10px;
 }
```

Check Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bZF48/17/