# How to use z-values?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I want to use box-shadow everywhere except from the top on this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/KquxS/2/

I'm pretty sure it can be done with z-values but I'm not sure how, as you can see I've had a little play trying but no luck.

Comment: What do you mean by you don't want to use shadows "from the top on" ?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but a z-index only works if you use it together with `position: absolute`, or `position: relative`. So in your example the z-index are not read at all...

Comment: Sorry, if you hover over the 'Register' link you should see the shadow appears around the whole menu. I only want it to show on the left, bottom and right (not the top).

Comment: have a look here then ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429605/creating-a-css3-box-shadow-on-all-sides-but-one

Comment: Here's a better example: http://jsfiddle.net/KquxS/9/

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using z-index.

Consider using the following style:

```
ul:not(:first-child) {
    box-shadow:0 0 40px black;
}
```

I'm gonna leave this but I think the comment you just posted helped clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: Could you edit the jsFiddle to show what you mean as I don't think that's what I'm after?

Comment: I thought you didn't want the box shadow to appear on the top 2 lists. I didn't realize you were talking about the edges of the lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `position: absolute`, you have to provide the position (`top`, `left`, etc) as well. Otherwise `position` and `z-index` have no effect and the elements will be drawn in the order they appear in the DOM.

See http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index