# How to make shadow gradient out of the div only in the left and right side?

Tags: css, gradient, shadow

I want to replace [Demo image](http://www.centerwow.com/stackoverflow/shadow1.jpg) by code css3 or somthing else.

I have a blue image on the image I have a white background,

on the side of the image and white background,

in the right and left sides I have a gradient shadow .

Can I do this shadow only on the sides using css3 or otherwise without the picture?

I try to do it here [jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/jJCwL/3/)

Thx.

Comment: There are multiple solutions on [a similar question over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429605/creating-a-css3-box-shadow-on-all-sides-but-one?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/jJCwL/4/

If you only want shadow at the right and left side:
http://jsfiddle.net/jJCwL/5/